# Find query with condition over 50 million+ records in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection with over 50 millions of documents. I need to find (with condition) through all documents at once. Here is an example of documents stored in DB.

```
[
{id:1, date:(timestamp), user: 1, content: debit done successfully},
{id:2, date:(timestamp),user: 2, content: credit done successfully},
{id:3, date:(timestamp),user: 1, content: debit done successfully},
{id:4, date:(timestamp),user: 3, content: debit done successfully},
]
```

Each date there are about 1.5-2 million entries with each user having multiple transactions. So i need to find e.g all debit transaction particular user done.

```
db.col.find({$and: [{user:1}, content:{$regex: /debit/, $options:'gi'}]})
```

I can't go for pagination approach, i need to find in all documents. What is the best way to deal with situation like this?

Comment: If you dont use pagination, then it will just create huge repsonse with a lot of fields. I dont get, whats the actual question? Do you want to help with indexes? Do you want to help with how to return that much data without client has to paginate? If so, then you need to write down your use-case.

Comment: I have created index on content field. For find query, i can't do pagination to search for 20 documents and again 20 and so on. In this way i'll not get total number of debit transactions that user have done. So i need to know how can i perform such find query which execute fasts. once data is available, i store and send to client in pagination.

Comment: Not able to get your requirement, but would suggest you add an index on 'user' instead of content. Also, regex queries are not good (comparatively)

Comment: @RajatGoel, i have demonstrated how i am retrieving records currently. So i need suggestion, is there better way to achieve the same when u query over millions of records?

Comment: It depends. You need to elaborate. Why do you need to have a million of entries in the result? Are you feeding some other system? How are you feeding it? Why you are using regex? Why no index on the id or a compound index?

Comment: An index on the user will be a requirement here, since the regex is case insensitive an index on content will basically do nothing. See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use